# how I can run this makefile(ubuntu, python2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, docker, ubuntu, makefile

my env are docker(newest), windows 10, ubuntu 20.04, python2.7

I downloaded these files from here
: https://github.com/andyreagan/core-stories.git

file name : makefile

this is file which I want to run

```
PYENV = pyvenv/bin/python
all: experiment control
experiment:
        # for I in 80 40 20 10;
        # do
        #     $PYENV src/hierarchical_clusting/hierarchical-clusting-004.py $I false
        #     $PYENV src/PCA_SVD/PCA-SVD-006.py $I false
        #     $PYENV src/SOM/SOM-002.py $I false
        # done
        for I in 40;
        do
                $PYENV src/hierarchical_clusting/hierarchical-clusting-004.py $I false
                $PYENV src/PCA_SVD/PCA-SVD-006.py $I false
                $PYENV src/SOM/SOM-002.py $I false
        done
control:
        # for I in 40;
        # do
        #     $PYENV src/hierarchical_clusting/hierarchical-clusting-004.py $I true
        #     $PYENV src/PCA_SVD/PCA-SVD-006.py $I true
        #     $PYENV src/SOM/SOM-002.py $I true
        # done
        for I in {1..10};
        do
                $PYENV src/PCA_SVD/PCA-SVD-006.py 40 true "-$I"
                $PYENV src/hierarchical_clusting/hierarchical-clusting-004.py 40 true "-$I"
                $PYENV src/SOM/SOM-002.py 40 true "-$I"
        done
```

but it doesn't work.

this is error messages

```
root@561836c32904:~/temp/core-stories# make
# for I in 80 40 20 10;
# do
#     YENV src/hierarchical_clusting/hierarchical-clusting-004.py  false
#     YENV src/PCA_SVD/PCA-SVD-006.py  false
#     YENV src/SOM/SOM-002.py  false
# done
for I in 40;
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "do")
make: *** [makefile:10: experiment] Error 2
```

please help I spent a week for this.

Comment: That makefile is broken and won't work.  No version of make I'm aware of will run it.

Comment: You could perhaps work around the problem you are asking about with `.ONESHELL:` but that will just push you further down into a rabbithole we don't wish to accompany you into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty attempt at guessing the author's intent.

```
.PHONY: all experiment control
all: experiment control

experiment:
    python src/hierarchical_clusting/hierarchical-clusting-004.py 40 false
    python src/PCA_SVD/PCA-SVD-006.py 40 false
    python src/SOM/SOM-002.py 40 false

control:
    for I in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10; do \
      python src/PCA_SVD/PCA-SVD-006.py 40 true "-$$I" \
      ; python src/hierarchical_clusting/hierarchical-clusting-004.py 40 true "-$$I" \
      ; python src/SOM/SOM-002.py 40 true "-$$I" \
    ; done
```

(Stack Overflow will render tabs as spaces so you won't be able to copy/paste this straightforwardly.)

Comment: Probably they also meant to write "clustering" and not "clusting" but ... stopping here.

Comment: Reported a bug: https://github.com/andyreagan/core-stories/issues/3